# Can't figure out ternary conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble figuring out this statement:

```
return this.savedValue ? 
        this.currentValue ? 
        this.currentValue : this.savedValue
        : this.currentValue
```

How would that look like in classical if else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better understanding you could write:

```
return this.savedValue
 ? (this.currentValue ? this.currentValue : this.savedValue)
 : this.currentValue
```

---

```
if (this.savedValue) {
  if (this.currentValue) {
    return this.currentValue;
  }
  else {
    return this.savedValue;
  }
} else {
  return this.currentValue;
}
```

Comment: I think that this can be simplified to `return this.currentValue ? this.currentValue : this.savedValue`; or even better `return this.currentValue || this.savedValue`

Comment: @DavidTáboas true but the question was more of a "can't understand" rather then "can we write this better", still your comment is welcome since it might help clarify for some other cases